# CesiumJS - add entity with image on top of base shape

Tags: angular, typescript, cesiumjs

**question:**

We using **CesiumJS** library in our app, and trying to add some complex entity without success.
The app should display entities from different types (base shapes), each entity should have its specific image.

**Is there a way to add the entity this way?**

**case description:**

I try to create entities on the map with base shape (like hexagon, circle,...) and image on top of the shape.
I am currently used PinBuilder for entity creation, but i want to display it with different pin shape style.
Each entity should have different base shape with different image.

---

**code example:**

```
`// cesium-map.directive.ts file
// current code - with PinBuilder
// its responsible to add new entity by its params
const entity = this.viewer.entities.add({
  id,
  description: type,
  position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(long, lat, 0),
  label: {
    text: name,
    font: '12px sans-serif',
    verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP,
    distanceDisplayCondition: new Cesium.DistanceDisplayCondition(0, 80000)
  },
  // maybe there something else then billboard / PinBuilder that can used here?
  billboard: {
    image: new Cesium.PinBuilder().fromUrl(
      options.cesiumIconUrl,
      isSelected ? selectedColor : options.color,
      30
    ),
    verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM
  }
});`
```

---

**system info:**

> os: windows 10
>
> browser: chrome 78
>
> cesium: 1.55.0
>
> angular: 5

---

**links:**

[CesiumJS](https://cesium.com/cesiumjs/)

[docs](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/)

---

I have been searching in Cesium docs and web resources for solution without success.

I would like to get some help here. :)

Comment: The Billboard's `image` input can also take a small 2D canvas that you have drawn an icon on.  You might be able to draw what you need onto a canvas and pass that in there.